# Why the screen-reader reads the styling of an SVG, when @svg directive is used (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, svg, screen-readers

I am having an issue with an SVG that i've used, using the @svg() directive in Laravel.

Here is how I am including the svg `@svg('trustpilot/5-rating')`.

Here is the SVG file I am including

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 37.5">
<defs>
    <style>.tp5-1{fill:#00b67a;}.tp5-2{fill:#fff;}</style>
</defs>
<title>Asset 4</title>
<g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
    <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
        <rect class="tp5-1" width="37.5" height="37.5"/>
        <rect class="tp5-1" x="40.63" width="37.5" height="37.5"/>
        <rect class="tp5-1" x="81.25" width="37.5" height="37.5"/>
        <rect class="tp5-1" x="121.88" width="37.5" height="37.5"/>
        <rect class="tp5-1" x="162.5" width="37.5" height="37.5"/>
        <path class="tp5-2" d="M18.75,25.27l5.7-1.44,2.39,7.34Zm13.12-9.49h-10L18.75,6.33l-3.09,9.45h-10l8.13,5.86-3.09,9.45,8.13-5.86,5-3.59,8.08-5.86Z"/>
        <path class="tp5-2" d="M59.38,25.27l5.7-1.44,2.38,7.34ZM72.5,15.78h-10L59.38,6.33l-3.09,9.45h-10l8.13,5.86-3.09,9.45,8.12-5.86,5-3.59,8.09-5.86Z"/>
        <path class="tp5-2" d="M100,25.27l5.7-1.44,2.39,7.34Zm13.13-9.49h-10L100,6.33l-3.09,9.45h-10L95,21.64l-3.09,9.45L100,25.23l5-3.59,8.09-5.86Z"/>
        <path class="tp5-2" d="M140.62,25.27l5.71-1.44,2.38,7.34Zm13.13-9.49h-10l-3.09-9.45-3.08,9.45h-10l8.12,5.86-3.08,9.45,8.12-5.86,5-3.59,8.09-5.86Z"/>
        <path class="tp5-2" d="M181.25,25.27l5.7-1.44,2.39,7.34Zm13.13-9.49h-10l-3.09-9.45-3.09,9.45h-10l8.13,5.86-3.09,9.45,8.13-5.86,5-3.59,8.09-5.86Z"/>
    </g>
</g>
```

The issues I am having is, the screen readers are reading out what I have in **defs** and **style** tags. So it goes...
.tp5-1{..... ect,ect...

I did some research and I found that I can pass some parameters to the @svg() directive, such as name, class and other parameters.

[image: So my question is, what parameter can I pass to the svg, in order to stop the screen readers read out what I have in the style tag and is that actually possible?]

Or do you have any other suggestions? I thought as we have a **title** tag in the SVG that would actually be used by the screen reader but I seem to be wrong.

Comment: In general, `<svg>` elements have sporadic support from screen readers. I'm not sure which screen reader you tested with (jaws, nvda, voiceover, talkback), but **none** of them should read the actual code or styling. `<title>` and `<text>` elements are *sometimes* read. If you have a codepen/jsfiddle example that shows the problem, I can try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I have sorted out the issue by giving the style tag a parameter of area-hidden=true, which seems to have resolved the issue.

It looks like this:

```
<style area-hidden="true">.tp5-1{fill:#00b67a;}.tp5-2{fill:#fff;}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It says you should be sending options, you can make something like

```
['class' => 'some class']
```

inside your @svg directive as 2. parameter.

[here](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-blade-svg-directive) you can read more.

Also your svg should be like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 37.5">
    <defs>
        <style>.tp5-1{fill:#00b67a;}.tp5-2{fill:#fff;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>Asset 4</title>
    <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
        <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
            <rect class="tp5-1" width="37.5" height="37.5"/>
            <rect class="tp5-1" x="40.63" width="37.5" height="37.5"/>
            <rect class="tp5-1" x="81.25" width="37.5" height="37.5"/>
            <rect class="tp5-1" x="121.88" width="37.5" height="37.5"/>
            <rect class="tp5-1" x="162.5" width="37.5" height="37.5"/>
            <path class="tp5-2" d="M18.75,25.27l5.7-1.44,2.39,7.34Zm13.12-9.49h-10L18.75,6.33l-3.09,9.45h-10l8.13,5.86-3.09,9.45,8.13-5.86,5-3.59,8.08-5.86Z"/>
            <path class="tp5-2" d="M59.38,25.27l5.7-1.44,2.38,7.34ZM72.5,15.78h-10L59.38,6.33l-3.09,9.45h-10l8.13,5.86-3.09,9.45,8.12-5.86,5-3.59,8.09-5.86Z"/>
            <path class="tp5-2" d="M100,25.27l5.7-1.44,2.39,7.34Zm13.13-9.49h-10L100,6.33l-3.09,9.45h-10L95,21.64l-3.09,9.45L100,25.23l5-3.59,8.09-5.86Z"/>
            <path class="tp5-2" d="M140.62,25.27l5.71-1.44,2.38,7.34Zm13.13-9.49h-10l-3.09-9.45-3.08,9.45h-10l8.12,5.86-3.08,9.45,8.12-5.86,5-3.59,8.09-5.86Z"/>
            <path class="tp5-2" d="M181.25,25.27l5.7-1.44,2.39,7.34Zm13.13-9.49h-10l-3.09-9.45-3.09,9.45h-10l8.13,5.86-3.09,9.45,8.13-5.86,5-3.59,8.09-5.86Z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I don't think adding a class to it will resolve the issue I have stated above, which is screen-readers reading out the text in the styling tag.

Comment: Did you try it? The poblem is it try to merge attributes. However, 2. parameter is not array.

Comment: That's not the problem am having, the image is just for example purposes of the svg method, do not focus on it.

Comment: Your error is that. The parameter that you send is not correct. Can you share how do you use your svg directive? The error screenshot that you says it got wrong parameter. If you share your code I'll try to do it on my local machine

Comment: Here is how am including the SVG file
-> `@svg('trustpilot/5-rating')`

Comment: Did you forget to close svg tag? And you do not have to use svg directive just include it from like any other blade view. Or just put it into your code if it is just 1 time thing to use.

Comment: AM sorry but it seems like you haven't read all the information I have provided above. I am struggling to understand what you are trying to tell me and I feel like you aren't understanding the issue I am having. Thank you for trying to help out though.